# Excel Macro : Find Max repeatedly in column after value=0

Tags: excel

I would like to repeatedly calculate the MAX value in a column, after the value in that column = 0 twice in a row. See example:

```
Torque (Lbf_in)

0

0

.827664554

9.673638344

45.82129669

60.63316727

58.07248688

38.35304642

18.0196209

4.054021835

0

0

...Repeat
```

We're finding the max torque per cycle of a handle using software that dumps it into excel. the double 0 values show us to reset to cycle the handle again, so we would like to capture the max value again after each double 0 value. The spread sheet has 1,800 cycles, so doing this manually is very time consuming. It's not consistently in the same number of rows that the cycle repeats (its based on time).

Thanks!

Comment: Are there always ***8*** samples between the zero pairs ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I think `It's not consistently in the same number of rows that the cycle repeats` says no they are not consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you data is in column A, please enter this formula in cell B4 and drag it to the bottom. `=IF(AND(A2=0,A3=0),MAX(OFFSET(A4,0,0,MATCH(0,A4:A700,0),1)),"")`

[image]

Also make sure to add one 0 at the end of your data.

Comment: I prefer the non volatile INDEX: `A4:INDEX(A4:A700,MATCH(0,A4:A700,0))` instead of `OFFSET(A4,0,0,MATCH(0,A4:A700,0),1)` but good formula.

Comment: You are a life saver! this works great. Can you explain in laymans terms how this works?

Comment: Sure, first it looks for double rows containing 0 value. When this condition evaluates to true, It uses offset function to create range in which max function will operate. I used Match function to find first occurring 0 below current row (that would be start of the next cycle ) then this match will give dynamic range in which max will operate...could you please mark as answered?